# Swift Package not available during testing

Tags: swift, xcode

Seems like a really newbie issue but I cannot for my life find an answer to this.

I just got started with SwiftUI and added my first Swift Package Dependency (GoogleSignIn) to my project. The app builds and runs fine.

But when I try to run my tests I get the following:

```
No such module 'GoogleSignIn'
```

So it works fine in normal target. But for my `XCTestCase`s it doesn't even build anymore. I added the package by going to my `project > Package Dependencies > +` and then just pasting in the URL https://github.com/google/GoogleSignIn-iOS.

How do I make the package available to my tests?

Comment: GoogleSignIn needs to be listed in two place: the project's Package Dependencies, and the app target's Frameworks, Libraries, and Embedded Content. Is it?

Comment: I can see both `GoogleSignIn` and `GoogleSignInSwift` under "Frameworks, Libraries, and Embedded Content" for the app. But there is no such section for the test target. Just "Supported Destinations", "Deployment Info" and "Testing".

Comment: There should not be such a section for the test target so that is expected. Are you trying to access the package directly in your tests?

Comment: No, the tests just import Foundation and XCTest. The error is for the file in the main app where the import is. But I can only get the error when I try to run the tests. Just opening the offending file makes the error go away... until I try to run the tests again. Any test.

Comment: You haven't given enough information to reproduce the issue. Throwing a bounty at it won't magically make the question better.

Comment: If you felt like specific information was missing, then you could always asked for it, and I would've gladly provided it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found the answer.

I opened up `MyApp.xcodeproj/project.pbxproj` and edited it by hand.

Specifically I edited the section named `Begin PBXFrameworksBuildPhase section` where there are 3 sections, and made sure that `files` looked the same for all three sections.

Then I repeated this for the section named `Begin PBXNativeTarget section` and the list `packageProductDependencies`.

After this the tests worked.

Comment: This answer doesn't grow in any way out of the information given in the question.